# How can a "non-function" be graphed?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am trying to create a program that requires the graphing of a *"non-function"*, i.e, a function where "x" isn't strictly dependent on "y".

Let's answer the obvious question: **Is it even possible?**

Yes, it is possible, as demonstrated by online graphing calculators such as [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org), as well as several other open-source softwares. However, I haven't had success in figuring out how these graphing calculators graph non-functions. I have done some research, and have found nothing helpful.

Now, I'm looking for means to graph *any* non-functions, not just simple ones such as a circle or a sideways parabola, which simply require the graphs of *+f(x)* and *-f(x)*. Maybe more complicated ones such as *`sin(x) + sin(y)= 1`*. The following graph is of the said non-function, as graphed by Desmos.

[image: sin(x)+sin(y)=1]

Any help on how to graph non-functions is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the time examples like these "look" like functions locally. Therefore they can broken up into little pieces by using a valid set of initial conditions or a function which is valid and describes part of the overall relation you are trying to graph.

In your example we can convert the equation to look like:

$$
y = sin^{-1}(1-sin(x))
$$

Which gives a starting point looking like the bottom half of a single warped sphere. Then we see that since $sin(y)=sin(\pi-y)$ we can cap the warped sphere. Then we can argue that the equation is clearly unchanged if we were to replace $(x,y)$ with $(x+2\pi n ,y+2\pi m)$ (for integer values of m,n) and so we can repeat our pattern throughout the entire grid due to the periodicity of the $sin$ function.

Another good example is $y^2 = x$ where we have two sets of solutions corresponding to $y=\pm \sqrt{x} $.

Comment: I really like your explanation. However, there is a problem. Some non-functions cannot be simplified exclusively to have y be dependent on x. For instance, `x arcsin( x/y) + sqrt( y^2 - x^2) = 4xy`, which isn't even symmetric like the other examples, but can still be graphed by Desmos.

Comment: If you are alright with approximate solutions then you can differentiate w.r.t. x to isolate for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then expand around as many sets of valid initial conditions as you can find. I'm sure there are some fancier tricks for finding a complete graph for an equation but I was just trying to point out that such an equation acts like a function somewhere around every set of valid initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

An aproach for this would be to take some values.
x arcsin( x/y) + sqrt( y^2 - x^2) = 4xy 
For example x=5. We substitute this value. And later we try different values for y until we have a equality (left part is some as right side). Some mechanisms help to do this, looking on how quick we get a approximation. I would first convert this to a equation equal to 0 :
x arcsin( x/y) + sqrt( y^2 - x^2) - 4xy = 0

This is trivial, and now for each x-value, we can get a y value (or many y-values) using a aproximation methode like Newton, which use derivates.

 Daniel

P.S. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Answer (score 0):

According from what you asked, let's see images below and take conclusions.

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/y7N0Pr3N1RY/maxresdefault.jpg
(points tracing)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAubS.png
(from the same equation in 3D graph)

To trace a XY graph which is non-function, it is actually calculate the equation with every X and Y in the graph in range.
And it is determined by intersection between XY plane.